# How do i disable a function in a function?

Tags: javascript, function, visualization

I have a game over function here:

```
function gameOver() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";
    ctx.fillText ("GAME OVER!", 424, 236.25);
}
```

I also have a score function here:

```
function Score() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000"
    ctx.font = "27px Ariel";
    ctx.fillText ("Score: " + score, 18.89, 30);
}
```

What i want is when i call the game over function then i want the score to not be visible. How can i do that???

I have tried:

```
function gameOver() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";
    ctx.fillText ("GAME OVER!", 424, 236.25);
    Score() = "none";
}
```

but it obviously didn't work, lol. Im kind of new to this, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had better use a variable to keep the current state of the game

```
var state ="PLAYING";
function gameOver() {
    if(state!== "PLAYING") return;
    state = "GAME_OVER";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";
    ctx.fillText ("GAME OVER!", 424, 236.25);
}
function Score() {
    if(state!== "PLAYING") return;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.font = "27px Ariel";
    ctx.fillText ("Score: " + score, 18.89, 30);
}

function playAgain() {
    state = "PLAYING";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are calling your score function after your gameOver function. Call the score function first.

What you can also do (to answer your question) is set the score function to something else:

`let Score = () => { original score function body here };`

Then inside gameOver, you can set:

`Score = () => {}; // empty function does nothing`

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here with `gameOver()` is to change style and text, then immediately call `Score()` that overwrites your style and text. Just remove it from there and it should be fine :)

Comment: If you look closely, `gameOver()` and `Score()` "fills text" at different locations. And OP wants to get rid of text filled by `Score()` when game is over.